# why is my constructed temporary object const not mutable?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue

I have a class `K` and I am constructing an object in a call to function `test`. So I believe that the constructed `K` is called an *r-value*. (Is that true?)

But I am puzzled, and bothered that the `K` object is apparently *const*, not *mutable*. I don't want it to be.

## Simple test program:

```
#include <iostream>

class K {};

std::string test (K &k) {return "mutable";}

std::string test (const K &k) {return "const";}

int main (int argc, const char **argv) {
  std::cerr << "K constructed for function argument is " << test(K{}) << "\n";
  K k;
  std::cerr << "K constructed for local variable is " << test(k) << "\n";
}
```

## Output:

> K constructed for function argument is const
>
> K constructed for local variable is mutable

Note that when I create the `K` on the fly for passing as function argument I get a const object, whereas when I create it as a local variable I get a mutable.

For my purposes I really want a mutable for both cases. Can you tell me how to do that, or else convince me why I shouldn't?

Comment: What the point of be able to *mutate* an object you are going to lose just after your function? The fact you want to do this probably mean you have a bad design either in your function or in your class.

Comment: You cannot bind an rvalue to a non-const reference. Some compilers offer this as an extension but I would stay well away from it.

Comment: I thought you might ask that! Without going into a lot of detail, here is one reason, which I believe is close to my use case:

Function test() calls some method m() of K that is non-const and uses the result to perform a side effect on objects that are not part of K. There may be legitimate reasons that m() was not const and the effects it has on the temporaray K are real, though irrelevant since K is going away.

Comment: @Holt, it is usually not that you want to mutate it, but that you call functions on it which are non-const.

Comment: @SergeyA which is saying the same thing, otherwise the functions would be const

Comment: @BeyelerStudios not neccessarily. They might be non-const because someone forgot to mark them cost, or the class might be designed in such a way that functions accept or return values through members of the class (sometimes this neccessary evil).

Answer (score 3):

A reference cannot bind to a temporary object but a `const T&` can.  Since `K{}` is a temporary `std::string test (const K &k) {return "const";}` is chosen.

If you really want to be able to modify the temporary then you can use and r-value reference

```
std::string test (K &&k) {return "r-value";}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d620922f0e445eba)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

In standard C++, you can not bind temporary object to non-const reference. You can bind it to rvalue references, though. Users of MSVC enjoy the 'extension' of binding temporaries to non-const references.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you got your syntax mixed up between l-value references and r-value references.

`K& k` : this is a non-const l-value reference. It can usually only be bound to variables that have names. This syntax implies (typically) you are taking in `k` and *modifying inside your function*, such that `k` is also the *output* of the function. Doing this with a temporary doesn't actually make sense, because the temporary will be gone. It only really makes sense to do for variables (esoteric compiler extensions aside).

`const K& k` : const reference. This can bind to l or r-values. This means you are using `k` within your function, but (generally) don't need to copy it, and certainly won't modify it. It's safe-enough, because you can't modify the temporary (so there's no implicit assumption that it will be used later), and the temporary will exist for the life of the function.

`K&& k` : This is an r-value reference. It implies move semantics, namely that the function using `k` will only accept a temporary value (or one made movable with `std::move`), and it will *take ownership* of said temporary.

In practice, the only place I've personally found necessary (or really even appropriate) to use r-value references is:

1. class constructors for containers. These should have a move constructor/move assigner, so that they can take ownership when created with temporary values.
2. forwarding functions. I.e. wrapper functions which only call lower-level class functions. If those low-level class functions support r-values, a *universal reference* can be used to make sure that support doesn't get messed up.

Your first instinct should probably be to avoid r-values in function calls.

On the other hand, if you were *actually* trying to bind the temporary to a non-const reference I think this question/answer has a better explanation as to why it's not allowed:
[How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)